# Redux store immutable pattern for nested data in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, redux

I've got a simple JSON data array that looks like this (it's the same in my Redux store and I store it under `properties`):

```
[
  {
    "id": "room",
    "name": "Room",
    "description": "Just a room",
    "foo": "bar",
  },
  {
    "id": "apartment",
    "name": "Apartment",
    "description": "just an apartment",
    "foo": "bar",
  }
]
```

It has to be an array because I'm mapping over it:

```
{properties.map(property => 
  <Property 
    id={property.id} 
    name={property.name} 
    description={property.description} 
    foo={property.foo}
 />)}
```

This way I have two properties rendered in my app.

The question is - how do I update `"foo"`in Redux?

This my reducer currently [written according to the docs](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#correct-approach-copying-all-levels-of-nested-data):

```
case 'UPDATE_FOO':
  return {
    ...state, 
    properties: {
      ...state.properties,
      [action.id]: {
      ...state.properties[action.id],
      foo: action.fooData,
    }
  }
}
```

Of course it throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'room' of undefined` because I'm trying to access `state.properties["room"]` and this does not exist.

I've been thinking about reshaping my JSON and Redux store, but once I change it to named objects I can't map over it...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your store to be an object, and generate the array, when you need to render it, by converting it to an array, using [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values):

```
{Object.values(properties).map(property => (
  <Property key={property.id} {...property} />
)}
```

If the order might change (sorting for example), you need to have another array with the ids to hold the order (see [redux normalized state](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape)):

```
{
  properties: {
    room: {
      "id": "room",
      "name": "Room",
      "description": "Just a room",
      "foo": "bar",
    },
    apartment: {
      "id": "apartment",
      "name": "Apartment",
      "description": "just an apartment",
      "foo": "bar",
    }
  }
}

{
  properties: {
    room: {
      "id": "room",
      "name": "Room",
      "description": "Just a room",
      "foo": "bar",
    },
    apartment: {
      "id": "apartment",
      "name": "Apartment",
      "description": "just an apartment",
      "foo": "bar",
    }
  },
  order: ['apartment', 'room']
}
    
{order.map(id => (
  <Property key={id} {...properties[id]} />
)}
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out the rendering of `Property` could be shortened to `Object.values(properties).map(property => <Property key={property.id} {...property}/>)`

Comment: I really like your answer, but setting up the store with JSON formatted like this: `const initialState = { myJsonData}` will end up with `state.properties.properties` and it adds another level to my reducer, am I right? :(

Comment: Nope - it's just `state.properties`. The array `properties` is replaced with an object `properties`.

Comment: @OriDrori hm, I must be doing something wrong then, but I think "properties" are dragged here form the JSON file: https://imgur.com/a/FECwFCq . Does'nt matter if i initialise store with `const initialState = {properties: myJsonData}` or `const initialState = {myJsonData}`, I'm always getting it doubled :[

Comment: You'll need to normalize the JSON when inserting it, which means that you'll need to iterate it, and create the shape of the state in the reducer.

Comment: I'm a moron, and you're right: `const initialState = {properties: myJsonData["properties"]}`.

Comment: I blame the late hour :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the store using but the Id. You can look up for the one element (you're trying to edit) in array of properties using the id, then to update it:

```
    case 'UPDATE_FOO':
        const newProperties = state.properties.map(property => {
            if(property.id === action.id) {
                return { ...property, foo: action.fooData}
            }
            return property;
        })
        return {
            ...state,
            properties: newProperties
        }
     }
```

Comment: This is great, but so hard to read and understand :( I guess I should go with immer at least then? It's a flat JSON and still updating a prop looks crazy like this.